# mongoose find in all subdocument Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my mongoose schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  images: [
    {
      fileName: String,
      location: String,
      fileExtension: String
    }
  ],
  documents: [
    {
      fileName: String,
      location: String,
      fileExtension: String
    }
  ]
})
```

Here, inorder to query subdocuments, we'll use like below:

```
const doc = await Users.findOne({'images._id' : '60d57c5435934431b8a27hf'})
//or
const doc = await Users.findOne({'documents._id' : '60d57c5435934431b8a27hf'})
```

is there any way to search in all subdocument arrays globally(i.e images and documents) by Id without explicitly mentioning which subdocumnt array to lokup?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$or` operator from [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```js
const doc = await Users.findOne({
  $or: [
    { 'images._id': docID },
    { 'documents._id': docID }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Popov. it sloves my problem.  btw, is there anyway to delete subdocument from either of the subdocumnet array by `subdocument.id().remove()` method or any other?

Comment: Yes, you can use `doc.images.pull(subdocumentID)`!

Comment: So, without specifying subdocument array i.e `doc.images` or `doc.documnets` we cannot delete it with `id` alone right?

Comment: Well if you think about it - you want to delete a specific subdocument, but you don't know where it is. It can be anywhere in the database, so how does Mongo know what to delete? :)